# Difference between AudioBuffer and ArrayBuffer and NodeJs Buffer in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, arraybuffer, audiobuffer

What is the differnce between different types of buffers in Javascript. Are they almost same? Is conversion between them possible? Please explain..

Comment: They are mostly unrelated, apart from the name.